# MAC OSX 10.12 Sierra -TOR cannot connect to control port mac os sierra fix

Tags: mac

I have updated to MAC OSX Sierra and now tor will open but just says: tor cannot connect to control port 
I have no firewall installed and no antivirus either.
Can someone please advice what may be the issue or what a fix could be please?
I have been using TOR for years and have never had an issue only now with Sierra there is an issue.
Thanks

Comment: This is not an answer. Forgive me as i do not know how to use this site yet. However i have encountered the same problem cannot connect to tor control port. i cannot open settings because of the same error and every time i re-download the same error occurs. i found this comment in another link but this doesn't help me as i cannot find this folder. perhaps this helps you: faced the same problem delete tor and from finder press - go - go to folder ~/Library/Application Support and delete the folder TorBrowser-Data then install 6.0.5. – Tor problem Sep 22 at 13:24

Answer (score 2):

I regret that I am slightly drunk plus doing this from memory, but I have suffered this exact same problem.

The issue is that a version of TorBrowser was released with a problem/feature that configuration files could not cope with space-characters in pathnames.

Unfortunately OSX likes to store configuration data in a folder called "$HOME/Library/Application[SPACE]Support" - and there are a lot of other directory names with spaces in them, in your OSX Library folder.

I can't recall *precisely* what I did to fix this, other than to manually check for anything Tor-related in my Library folder:

```
find ~/Library/ | egrep -i 'tor(project|browser)'
```

...and delete it; subsequent versions of the browser will stop picking up old, poisonous configuration files that way. **DO NOT** do this blindly because it will delete your bookmarks too.  Copy those to a safe place, first.

Answer (score 1):

It appears if you execute the distributed Firefox using `sudo` it works.

So from the terminal try:

```
sudo /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
```

Comment: Um, really? Run firefox as root...? That seems needlessly dangerous.

Comment: Thanks all...If anyone could provide any other ideas it would be super helpful, i have emailed TOR support to let them know but as yet no reply.

Comment: Running TorBrowser as `root` is dangerous, foolhardy and wrong